# Small difference in Texture UVs when in object mode :(

Tags: texturing, uv, object-mode

when i have my mesh in edit mode it looks fine:

[image]

(look at the concrete seams). But as soon i switch into object mode they get distorted:

[image]

I just dont understand why. I had a bevel modifier applied earlier but it is applied as you can see in the modifier tab.
Does anybody know a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please place your images in your question directly.  It show more effort on your part.

Comment: it also fails with an upload error :/

Comment: Do you know how to use GIMP? or other image software at no incremental cost to you? to capture a smaller image showing the same problem.  The application window of Blender can be reduced to result in a smaller image size.  Your image at the link has other portions not related to Blender.

Comment: ok ill create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it accidentally, I just created a new mesh and joined it to the existing one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and then the UVs updated and were ok.

Comment: A Fresh Start at low cost is effective.